# How to use the do while loop to push a string into an array multiple times?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop, do-while

I am very close...I think. Trying to use a do while loop to push "I love the Beatles!" into the array (n) amount of times including the 0 of whatever number is entered.

Implement a do-while loop inside the function that adds "I love the Beatles!" to the empty array.

The loop should then increment the number passed in as a parameter. The condition of the loop should check to see that the parameter number is less than 15. It should contain a number of strings that represents the difference between the input number and 15.

Return the array with the strings "I love the Beatles!".

I have tried what I have learnt so far on this course. Any explanation would be much appreciated!

```
function iLoveTheBeatles(n) {
  let newArray = [];
  let LoveBeatles = newArray.push("I love the Beatles!");

  do {
    LoveBeatles;
    return newArray;
  } while (n < 15);

  if (n > 15)
    newArray.push(LoveBeatles);

  return newArray;
}
```

```
1) Beatles Loops iLoveTheBeatles returns an 
array of 'I love the Beatles!' 8 times 
when passed the parameter 7 :

Error: Expected [ 'I love the Beatles!' ] 
to equal 
[ 'I love the Beatles!', 'I love the Beatles!', 
'I love the Beatles!', 'I love the Beatles!', 
'I love the Beatles!', 'I love the Beatles!', 
'I love the Beatles!', 'I love the Beatles!' ]
```

Comment: what is n? here array length,you have a really messed up code

Comment: n will be a number that is passed through. Is it best to leave the parenthesis empty? So if 7 is put in, it wants the string in the array 8 times (including 0).

Comment: Why not using a `for` loop instead?

Comment: Because it's part of the online course. I know there are other ways to do things but they want me to use the do while loop.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. But, `LoveBeatles` will be the `length` of the `newArray` after `push` and it will always be `1`

Comment: Exactly, so I need it multiple times(n) times to be exact, I have tried using .repeat

Comment: not sure what you mean with _It should contain a number of strings that represents the difference between the input number and 15_. Can you please give **in plain text** what an expected output is for 5 or for 25 for example.

Comment: Yeah that was poorly written by the course. It just wanted it to print once for anything over 15. Jack Bashford's answer below solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `LoveBeatles` a function. You also need to `return` from the function at the end - and increment `n` to avoid an infinite loop.

```js
function iLoveTheBeatles(n) {
  let newArray = [];
  let LoveBeatles = () => newArray.push("I love the Beatles!");
  do {
    LoveBeatles();
    n++;
  } while (n < 15);
  if (n > 15) LoveBeatles();
  return newArray;
}

const res = iLoveTheBeatles(7);

console.log(res);
console.log(res.length);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: This is amazing and you taught me something very valuable!  Thank you!

Comment: What will the `if (n > 15) LoveBeatles();` do, it's unnecessary because n will always be equal to 15 after finishing `do-while` loop

Comment: @Ammar But what if the loop never runs?

Comment: It'll always run at least one time because it's a `do-while` loop, not a `while` loop

Comment: Oh, I see - didn't know about that. So the conditional occurs at the *end* of each iteration. Cool!

Comment: Yep! I had to erase the LoveBeatles() after the (n >15) on the if and just return the newArray. Not sure as to why though. I passed but trying to understand that...

Comment: I see. Thanks @Ammar that makes sense now.

Comment: You should put an `if (n >= 15) return newArray;` before executing `do-while` loop

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're trying to push a string n times into an array and return this array as a result of the function call. a do-while loop is not a good solution for this, because if you pass 0 to the function it should return an empty array, right? but a do-while loop with iterate at least once until the "while" check is done. This is how it differs from a while loop. So, try this instead:

```js
function iLoveTheBeatles(n) {
    let loveTheBeatlesNTimes = [];
    let target = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(n - 15, 2))

    if (target > 0) {
        do {
            loveTheBeatlesNTimes.push('I Love The Beatles')
        } while (--target > 0)
    }

    return loveTheBeatlesNTimes;
}

console.log(iLoveTheBeatles(10)) // should output 5 times
console.log('----------')
console.log(iLoveTheBeatles(17)) // should output 2 times
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: 0 is meant to count as 1 per the error. It has to be a do while loop as part of the course. I know it's not best practice though.

Answer (score 0):

By defining your `LoveBeatles` the way you did, you are already pushing the string `"I love the Beatles"` onto the new array. I am quite sure, you did not intend do this.

If you just wish to push your desired string `n` times onto an array, there are multiple options. The most native one is a `for` loop:

```
function iLoveTheBeatles(n) {
  const newArray = [];
  // throw error for invalid n
  if (n < 0) {
    throw new Error("Input value n is negative");
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    newArray.push('I love the Beatles!');
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

A `while` loop solution could look like this:

```
function iLoveTheBeatles(n) {
  const newArray = [];
  // throw error for invalid n
  if (n < 0) {
    throw new Error("Input value n is negative");
  }
  while (newArray.length < n) {
    newArray.push('I love the Beatles!');
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Funny, I did intend to do that but I want to do it multiple times and it has to be a do while loop as per the course. Thanks though.

Comment: I see... so your intention is to make the test fail? It won't be true if you push it once no matter how n looks like. Otherwise you would need to check for  `n > 0`.

Comment: It's ok Jack Bashford gave me a brilliant solution. I had tried using the repeat method with n but it was lacking as it wasn't repeating the 0 as one.

Comment: In programming, a zero generally should never be interpreted as a 1, thus the array should be empty. If you do not follow this rule you will spent lots of time debugging in the future.

Comment: Cheers, yeah makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reapet` to multiple the text, then `split` by special char, i.e `~` and finally remove last value:

```js
var text = "I love the Beatles!~".repeat(4).split('~');
text.pop(); // remove last empty value
console.log(text)
```